# How to test a module in a describe block, and then mock it in another

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking

Assume we have 2 async modules in a file `module.js` which I test them in `module.test.js`. I’ve imported them as:

```
import { fn1, fn2 } from './module';
```

and tested `fn1` on a dedicated `describe` block, No issues there.

`f2` uses `f1` internally. I want to mock `f1` to test `f2` when it fails and succeeds.

Unfortunately it doesn’t work cause if I mock it as:

```
jest.mock('./module', () => ({
  f1: jest.fn(),
}));
```

then the other tests fail:

> TypeError: (0 , _module.fn1) is not a function

All samples in [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmockdocsenjest-objectjestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter) deal with a single function imported, in my case there are more than one, and mocking the file as done above, affects all of them.

Any idea how to mock `fn1` only for the `describe` block that tests `fn2`?

Comment: Why not separating those two tests into multiple files?

Comment: @Dominik A. I still have to import `fn2` while mocking the same file for `fn1`, so the issue is still there. B. It's against my project structure and I rather keep them in one file unless there's no other choice.

Comment: Could you share more code?

Comment: @Gordian take a look [here](https://github.com/LiskHQ/lisk-desktop/pull/3210/files#diff-7d159545a5be20b97577d34ca5f2c8728724e7832f2a6b37cdebfcf9990e35e6). It's more complex than I explained. I'm trying to test `getRegisteredDelegates` which uses `getTransactions` internally.

Comment: Can you show the code of `module.js` file?

Comment: In order to write a proper test you should not mock parts of the implementation (f1), but rather it's dependencies.

Comment: You'd be able to achieve this by using `jest.spyOn('fn1', module).mockReturnValue(...)`, but it's not a good approach